# Another question in relation to Tychonoff theorem

Tags: general-topology, compactness, filters

Let $X_i$ be compact topological spaces and let $X = \prod_{i \in I}X_i$ and let $\mathscr F$ be ultrafilter on $X$. Define $\mathscr F_i = \{Y \subseteq X_i : \pi_i^{-1}Y \in \mathscr F\}$. Here $\pi_i : X \to X_i$ is projection mapping.

I am trying to show that if $X_i$ are Hausdorff then $|\bigcap \mathscr F_i| = 1$. So far all my tries fail and I am starting to doubt if it is true. But I also fail to make counterexample.

Thank you for any help.

(Some things I have proved so far:

If $X_i$ are Hausdorff then $X$ is also Hausdorff.

If $\mathscr F$ is ultrafilter then $|\bigcap \mathscr F| \le 1$. I

f $X_i$ is compact then $|\bigcap \mathscr F_i| > 0$.)

Comment: It seems that the last claim is not always true. Consider a case when $|I|=1$ and $\mathcal F_i$ is a free ultrafilter. Moreover, it seems that this is also a counterexample for the claim, which you are trying to prove. It seems that in some intersections should be the closures of filter elements.

Comment: Did you try: If $\mathscr F$ is an ultrafilter, then $\mathscr F_i$ is an ultrafilter?